# shortcode in a custom metabox

Tags: custom-field, metabox, shortcode, post-meta

I am trying to add a shortcode from a plugin to my custom metabox. I have read it isn't the done thing but in this case i do need it to work. The client might not add a video but might add an image into it or something is so need to make sure it can still work for standard content.

The issue I am having is that it is outputting just the shortcode like so - [youtube id="vfGZZJnoJ0U"]

I have tried adding filters to my metabox but still showing that.

This is my custom metabox setup:

```
add_action('add_meta_boxes', 'testimonials_meta_box');
function testimonials_meta_box() {
    add_meta_box('testimonials_content_id', 'Testimonial Image/Video', 'testimonials_meta_box_cb', 'kleiser_testimonials', 'normal', 'high');
}

function testimonials_meta_box_cb($post) {
    global $post;
    wp_nonce_field('testimonial_content_nonce', 'testimonial_content_meta_box_nonce');
    $values = get_post_custom($post->ID);

    $left_content = isset($values['testimonial_content']) ? $values['testimonial_content'][0]: '';

    wp_editor($left_content, 'testimonial-content');
}

function testimonial_content_save($post_id) {
    if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) return;
    if(!isset($_POST['testimonial_content_meta_box_nonce']) || !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['testimonial_content_meta_box_nonce'], 'testimonial_content_nonce')) return;
    if(!current_user_can('edit_pages')) return;

    if(isset($_POST['testimonial-content'])) {
        update_post_meta($post_id, 'testimonial_content', $_POST['testimonial-content']);
    }
}
add_action('save_post', 'testimonial_content_save');
```

The only odd thing I am doing is I am storing each posts value of the metabox in an array and then doing a for loop and outputting them. That code is:

**Edit:**

This is my template page which has all my code:

```
<div id='hear_what_say_container'>
<?php $wp_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'kleiser_testimonials', 'posts_per_page'=> -1 )); ?>
<?php if ($wp_query->have_posts()) :
    $counter = 0;
    $total = $wp_query->post_count;
    $testimonialsContentArray = array();
?>
<!-- <div class='testimonial'></div> -->
<div id='main_testimonials'>
    <div class='testimonial_row'>
        <?php while ($wp_query->have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php
            $media = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'testimonial_content', true);
        ?>
        <?php array_push($testimonialsContentArray, array('id' => get_the_ID(), 'title' => get_the_title(), 'content' => get_the_content(), 'testimonialMedia' => $media )); ?>

        <div class='testimonial' data-id='<?php the_ID(); ?>'>
            <div class='testimonail_padding'>
                <?php
                    if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                        the_post_thumbnail();
                    }
                  ?>
                <div class='arrow_indicator'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <?php $counter++; ?>

        <?php if($counter % 5 == 0 || $counter == $total ): ?>
    </div>

    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php
        foreach($testimonialsContentArray as $testimoninalContent) {
    ?>
        <div class='testimonial_details' data-testimonial='<?php echo $testimoninalContent['id']; ?>'>
            <div class='detail_left testimonial_content'>
                <div class='detail_padding'>
                    <?php
                        echo wpautop($testimoninalContent['testimonialMedia']);
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class='detail_right testimonial_content'>
                <div class='detail_padding'>
                    <h1><?php echo $testimoninalContent['title'] ?></h1>
                    <?php echo wpautop( $testimoninalContent['content'] ); ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php
        }
    ?>
    <?php //endif; ?>
        <?php if($counter % 5 == 0 && $counter < $total ): ?>
        <div class='testimonial_row'>
            <?php $testimonialsContentArray = array(); ?>
        <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</div></div>
```

I am scratching my head for quite some time and not working out why I can't get the shortcode to work.

Any help would be really appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the answers below fail to solve things for you, please post your code is such a way that it can be easily copied into a dev stack and tested.

Comment: would you like me to add all my html for the page?

Comment: Well, no. I don't think I need all of the code but it looks like you've created a metabox and callback to save data but it is not clear where/what the connection is to the last two blocks of code.

Comment: Well it might actually be easier to add my html as that will show that i do a loop and grab the metabox content then put it into an array and out put the arrays content lower down the html

Comment: Alright. I assume that you have tried the suggestions below?

Comment: I have just change the code snippets to my whole template page html. I have tried all answers below but as much as i can see they should work they don't

Comment: I can't seem to add all of my template. there might be something in the lower half that might be causing an issue. I can't seem to paste it in cleanly for you to see it. Is there a way i can email/message you the full template?

Comment: I got it to work :). what i did was the apply_filters option. But the first time i did that it didn't work. So i went and had a look at my custom post type. i change the url using the rewrite and then flushed rewrite rules and now it works

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed that your are using `get_the_content()`, but it will return unfiltered content.

The shortcodes are generated via the `the_content` filter with priority `11`.

So if you want

- only the shortcodes generated, try:

  ```
  'content' => do_shortcode( get_the_content() )
  ```
- to filter it through `the_content` filter, try:

  ```
  'content' => apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() )
  ```
- to simulate [`the_content()`](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.7.1/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L156) function, try:

  ```
  'content' => str_replace(']]>', ']]&gt;', apply_filters( 'the_content', get_the_content() ) )
  ```

Comment: Hi Thanks for replying. I tried all 3 of those options you gave me but none worked :(. I don't know what to do

Comment: And you are sure this is a real shortcode you are testing?

Comment: Yer. As for some reason If i add it to the about page it works but add it to another page or this custom metabox it just outputs the shortcode. It's really strange. Unfortunatly I cant give access to the dev site. but can show you html/code you need

Comment: I noticed recently that the `[embed]` shortcode is not generated via `do_shortcode()`, you have to use `$GLOBALS['wp_embed']->run_shortcode()` instead. Not sure if that's a similar issue here? Where does your `[youtube]` shortcode comes from?

Comment: i just tried changing the do_shortcode to what you suggested but still not working :(. I get that youtube shortcode from the plugin called Advanced Responsive Video Embedder

Comment: I have tested to make sure its not the plugin thats not working but if i go to the page of the custom post type post it works. it just isn't working on that page. so i think im doing something wrong on that template

Comment: I got it to work :). what i did was the second option and apply_filters. But the first time i did that it didn't work. So i went and had a look at my custom post type. i change the url using the rewrite and then flushed rewrite rules and now it works

Comment: ok great to hear that it finally worked ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`do_shortcode()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/do_shortcode) function. In your case this would be something like this:

```
<?php
     echo do_shortcode(wpautop($testimoninalContent['testimonialMedia']));
?>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply. I tried this and still only outputs the shortcode code.

Answer (score 0):

`wpautop` just add breakspaces and paragraph to content.

Could you try, instead of

```
echo wpautop($testimoninalContent['testimonialMedia']);
```

to use the whole content filters with

```
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $testimoninalContent['testimonialMedia'] );
```

This way, whatever contains the custom field (a link to a video, a image, some text, or a shortcode, it will be treated as `the_content()` (and so, executing shortcodes).

I may be wrong here, so let us know ?

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I have tried doing this myself but not worked. Im now thinking my issue isnt to do with a shortcode as when i place the shortcode in some pages in the page editor it works and on some pages it doesn't. Any idea why that would be?